# Haskell list comprehension on variable number of strings

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, ghc

If I have two strings I use a list comprehension to obtain the desired result:

```
 combineStrings firstStr sndStr = [ [a,b] | a <- firstStr, b <- sndStr]
```

For three strings, I use this

```
 combineStrings firstStr sndStr trdStr = [ [a,b,c] | a <- firstStr, b <- sndStr, c <- trdStr]
```

What I'm trying is to obtain the same result for a variable number of strings. For example if I have a function which takes the following form:

```
 combineStrings :: [String] -> [String]
```

I'm trying to obtain the same results as above for 2, 3 ... n lists... I tried multiple ways, like this one

```
 combineStrings []      = []
 combineStrings (hd:tl) = [ a:b | a <- hd, b <- combineStrings tl]
```

but this fails because of [] on the first clause. Can someone help me to write this, please?

Comment: As a general rule, you can try to make types as general as possible. Here your code is not specific to strings, and can be used for all lists, so you can write `combineStrings :: [[a]] -> [[a]]`. Then, the first line from undur_gongor's answer can be written `combineStrings [] = [[]]`. You can also try to write `combineStrings` using `foldr`, as it fits the fold pattern.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
combineStrings [] = [""]
```

or better (as pointed out by [sdcwc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100020/sdcvvc)):

```
combineStrings [] = [[]]
```

Otherwise the part `b <- combineStrings tl` of the list comprehension will not yield any `b` and you will always end up with an empty array.

It also makes sense as an edge case: The only way to combine characters from zero strings is an empty string (consisting of zero characters).

Answer (score 15):

Noteworthy: Haskell already has that function, just a bit more general:

```
Prelude> :t sequence
sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]
Prelude> sequence ["ab","cd","12"]
["ac1","ac2","ad1","ad2","bc1","bc2","bd1","bd2"]
```

`[]` is an instance of `Monad`, so in this case the signature becomes `sequence :: [[a]] -> [[a]]`, with `a = Char`, `sequence :: [String] -> [String]`.

Comment: I wonder how many functions like this are re-written by newcomers like me.. But it's a learning experience :) Thank you

Comment: Many. And it's a good thing, as long as they're told soon enough that there's a (more general, usually) function in the standard libraries already, because, as you said, it's a _very good_ learning experience. Just, once you've figured out how it works by writing your own version, use the library function other Haskellers already know.

Comment: Hoogle and HLint are there to help you.

Comment: @Adi @DanielFischer And actually, at this point, a good exercise would be to write one's own implementation of `sequence`.  These simple-but-very-general functions always make good learning exercises.